# Something is wrong with windows 10 Bluetooth pairing system

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, window

I'm now on a 64 bit original windows 10 that came with HP preinstalled, all updates are installed, I have some Broadcom chip and I have tested my brother's Toshiba he has some other brand and it still suck as much. Of all OS I've used, Windows and Linux, windows 10 Bluetooth system suck the most.

When Pairing a device sometimes it works, but often it seems to be paired but in fact it doesn't work and YouTube or the movie you're watching stops working. What's even worse, is that say I paired a speaker, next time I have to use it, it's not going to detect it, I have to remove the device and pair it again - multiple times and I should keep turning the Bluetooth off and on from windows and try again.

Why is that happening and how to fix it or is it possible to use another Bluetooth manager, like in linux. why do i have to remove and re-add devices every time i want to use them?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: @Ramhound what's not clear about it so i can fix it, and an original jbl stereo isn't exactly cheap, and my cheap chinese headset costs 30$ which  is also not cheap by the chinese standards

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for pointing that out, removed that part

Comment: @Ramhound `say I paired a speaker, next time I have to use it, it's not going to detect it, I have to remove the device and pair it again - multiple times and I should keep turning the Bluetooth off and on from windows and try again` why is that happening and how to fix it or is it possible to use another bluetooth manager, like in linux. why do i have to remove and re-add devices everytime i want to use them? no one else had that issue? you didn't?

Comment: Nope;  I have never had that issue.  Everything you said in that comment should be in the question, if its not already, not in a positon to compare and constrast.

Comment: FWIW, you are using the bluez stack in Linux anyway. The different "bluetooth managers" are just different GUIs.

Comment: @TomYan yes I know and I had driver issues and the windows gui got stuck often, I had to exit and enter again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked JBL about it and they said

> Windows 10 does not support A2DP stereo audio streaming via Bluetooth,
>   the standard for music-listening through Bluetooth. The system will
>   support keyboards, mouse, printers etc. via Bluetooth, but not audio.
>
> It is necessary to download the proper drivers, either from the
>   computer manufacturer, the software manufacturer or the manufacturer
>   of the Bluetooth chip in the computer.

Anyway Windows seemed to have solved this issue in their newest update which was released someday this week I believe, version 1607, and now the bluetooth devices are working.

Turn on the bluetooth toggle and the connect toggle from action center.

---

NB: Tom believes that the quote is wrong, so let me say this, I do know that most of you have working bluetooth speakers, including my best friend. And personally I don't even care if Windows supported A2DP prior to this version, all I want to do is close this question and provide all the information I can to those who have the same problem.

So if you do have a problem with the quoted text, go to JBL.com and bash their technical team for providing false information. All I care about is that MY PROBLEM got fixed only after the last update.

Comment: Windows 10 supports A2DP fine. There is the `BthA2DP.sys` et. al. driver in its built-in bluetooth driver / stack. It even supports apt-X since build 10240.  At least it's working fine for me with version 1511 / build 10586.

Comment: Note that since Bluetooth uses the 2.4Ghz ISM bands, it can be interfered my many devices such as 802.11b/g/n wifi, wireless keyboard and mouse, and even any USB 3.x devices.

Comment: @TomYan if you're downvoting because of the quote, JBL support said that not me, other than that i don't get why downvoting, and I didn't have any wireless devices attached, now it's working with the new update. Again  I don't see why downvote and I know that for some people like you and my friend everything was working fine. This answer is a reference for people who had issues, so they know that they have to update

Comment: It doesn't really matter who said it. The information is simply wrong. Not to mention that the answer does not logically make sense to your issue anyway (although not clearly stated, it seems that the speakers _sometimes_ worked for you under Windows 10 as well). FWIW, "any USB 3.x devices" includes "wired" devices like portable hard drives. [For your reference](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/whitepapers/327216.pdf).

Comment: @TomYan the speakers never worked for me  and nor for a billion other people who still have open issus on microsoft forums, just a sample http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_devices/bluetooth-speaker-not-working-windows-10-build/af390308-641b-4422-98f9-c5e22b926ac1?auth=1 so go ahead and help them instead of arguing with me, because you're not giving any advice to help me fixing the issue, which i fixed without your help but when i needed your help you werent there. youre just trying to prove a point.

Comment: @TomYan i dont care if what youre saying is true, i had a problem that needed to be solved. no one here helped me, no one on microsoft forums helped people like me, so I reached to jbl, they didnt help either but at least they said something, so I tried to upgrade, maybe it would fix the problem and it did, had that not worked, I wouldve been googling for drivers, because you wouldnt help, you just bash

Comment: You no longer need any help when I saw your question. As a user of this site, I downvote any answer with wrong information. (And I did provide reason/explanation.) I haven't been denying that 1607 might have helped you and others though. (Maybe there was a bug in the builtin driver that causes trouble particularly to some Broadcom chips, but not CSR chips like the one I am on.)

Comment: No one is "bashing" you here. At least not me. All I did was just to avoid wrong knowledge from spreading further.

Comment: @TomYan point taken and included in my updated answer